# Lazy Git repository updater

Tags: git, repository, lazy-evaluation, hosted

I'm using Git as the repository for my hosted-server web application.

I know the way you're *supposed* to use a local repository with a remote project is to copy each file you edit to your local machine and add it to the repository to keep changes up to date.

My question is:  If I usually edit or create lots of new files every day, is there any way for me to just commit all the changes I've made all at once to my repository without having to update each file individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add them all at once (including new files) and then commit them. If you want to "rollback" you will have no way to just rollback a single file. Better create a commit for every issue you've been working on.

```
git add *
git commit -m "Todays changes.."
```

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was looking for.  In the near future I hope to have a more structured method of version control, however for now since I'm still doing so much varied development on a daily basis this will have to do.